# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Time'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to sum minutes keeping in my table.

```
class Time(models.Model):
    value = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
```

I'm trying to sum minutes in def function:

```
def sum(request):
   times = ..._set.all()
    for time in times:
        total_min = total_min + time
```

Then I have TypeError:

> unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Time'.

The problem appears because I'm trying to summarize values of different types: int + object type. And to solve the problem I need to convert object model PositiveIntegerField into int. But how can I do this not in class, but in def function?

Comment: `total_min = total_min + (time.value or 0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `time` is a `Time` object, and you can not add an `int` and a `Time` object together. What you can do is take the `.value` of the `Time` object. Since `.value` can be `None`, we should work with `time.value or 0` to add `0` in case the value is `None` or `0`, so:

```
def sum(request):
    some_object = …
    total_min = 0
    for time in some_object.time_set.all():
        total_min += time.value or 0
```

But this is not very efficient: it requires to fetch all `Time` objects from the database, and then performs the aggregation in at the Django/Python layer. You can do this at the database side with a [**`Sum`** expression <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#sum) in an [**`.aggregate(…)`** clause <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate):

```
from django.db.models import Sum

def sum(request):
    some_object = …
    total_min = some_object.time_set.aggregate(total=Sum('value'))['total']
```

---

> **Note**: Please do *not* name a variable `sum`, it overrides the reference to the [**`sum`** builtin function <sup>[Python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum). Use for example `sum_view`.